# "I am unable to change the XMP copyright status

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks, hyperxmp, xmp

When I use the

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}
```

packages, I am unable to change the copyright status to **Copyrighted**. It defaults to **Unknown** in the XMP.

Expected Output: (Before using those packages)

[image]

Current Output: (After using the package's)

[image]

MWE is below

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}


\hypersetup{
   pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
   pdftitle={O Hai},
   pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.,
    }

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a current LaTeX (and if you want to tag your document you should use a current LaTeX!) you should use `\DocumentMetadata` and loading the testphase package is not needed anymore.

`hyperxmp` is not compatible with the PDF management and it's loading is suppressed.

Unlike `hyperxmp` the PDF management doesn't set the `xmpRights:Marked` automatically. I was unsure if the logic in `hyperxmp` is correct: it sets it always to True if there is a value in pdfcopyright and has no option to set to False (Public Domain). But I forgot to add an interface to set the status explicitly, this will be corrected in the next version, until then you can add it like this:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
   pdfauthor={Brent Longborough},
   pdftitle={O Hai},
   pdfcopyright=Copyright © 2012 by Brent Longborough. All rights reserved.,
    }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdfmeta_xmp_add:n{<xmpRights:Marked>True</xmpRights:Marked>}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The provided code is functioning well. Thanks to Mr. Ulrike Fischer.

Comment: Not `Mr.`, I'm  woman.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but I think that the information is of general interest:

At least in the USA, an XMP copyright status "unknown" does not mean that the work has no copyright. All it means is what it says: The software that prepared the XMP does not know about the copyright status. The actual copyright notice will be somewhere visible on one of the PDF pages. For a traditional paper-printed book, that would usually be page iv in frontmatter.

As far as I know, when any software creates PDF with XMP, the default is "unknown". The user can change it to an actual copyright notice in XMP, or can change it to something equivalent to Public Domain (do not do that!).

The main issue with putting a copyright notice in XMP, is the risk that it will not be identical to the visible copyright notice in the PDF page. Then what? Of course, the XMP could merely direct attention to the visible copyright notice.

If a work has copyright in XMP, some commercial print services will refuse to print it, without written permission from the copyright holder. This has actually happened to me (no problem, I was on-site). On the other hand, especially with digital distribution, an XMP copyright may be required.

Related: If you self-publish using a pseudonym as author, be sure that the copyright notice shows your real name. Otherwise, how would you prove that the author is you, if you need to enforce copyright?

Other nations may differ, or this may evolve with time.